# Drupal Feature Recreate Module - what next

Tags: features

I am newer to drupal features. I have a site that was built heavily with them.

There is a drupal-feature where I added some fields. After I added and reorganized them I recreated the module.

Do I need to uninstall the current drupal feature module then install the new one?
Or can I just add the new module turn it on and go from there?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Modifying, updating and reverting Features](https://drupal.org/node/582680):

> The "recreate" button in the web-based administration interface is the equivalent to "update". However, the modified code will be provided for download as a .tar archive, instead of overwriting the existing feature module. It is up to the site builder to manually unzip and re-upload the modified module, replacing the original.

Comment: And as always dont forget to clear the cache...